# How to compare LocalDateTime to lastModified timestamp of a file?

Tags: java, java-time

I want to retrieve all files from a local folder whose modification date is older than midnight:

```
LocalDateTime midnight = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
long timestamp = file.lastModified();
```

Question: Now I have the start of the day in `java.time.LocalDateTime`, and the files' timestamp in `long`. How can I now check if `timestamp > midnight`?

Answer (score 1):

The following converts `LocalDateTime` to timestamp long:

```
long millis = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your question, you want to check whether the file was modified today. The following code may be a bit longer than the one in your own answer, but I believe it expresses the intent more clearly:

```
    long timestamp = file.lastModified();
    final ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Pacific/Nauru");
    LocalDate fileModifiedDate = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp)
            .atZone(zone)
            .toLocalDate();
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
    if (! fileModifiedDate.isBefore(today)) { // timestamp >= midnight
        // do something
    }
```

I am deliberately not using `fileModifiedDate.equals(today)`, which still more directly would express “file is modified today”. File modification times may be artificially set in the future, so for most purposes we want to stick to the `>=` comparison. You decide what is more correct for your purpose.

If you want today’s date in the JVM’s time zone, it is correct to use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` as in your answer, you can do that here too. Just know that the JVM’s time zone setting may be changed at any time by other parts of your program or other programs running in the same JVM.